# How to set up a WebSocket for Azure

Tags: azure, web, websocket, blazor

I have a Blazor project in Visual Studio 2022. It runs fine both locally and on Azure cloud (I publish it from Visual Studio).

I wanted to add a WebSocket server to this app. (I have previously done this on Azure but using Node, not C#)

I am using websocket-sharp ([websocket-sharp](https://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/))

Locally it all works fine.

I am creating the server in one of my Blazor service .cs files like so:

m_WSServer = new WebSocketServer(3333, false);

and adding a service to this like so:

m_WSServer.AddWebSocketService("/" + "Laputa");

and this service just returns a message when it receives one, like so:

Send("Elvis Lives!");

Now, in my .razor file I am creating the client like so (where 11.22.33.44 is the IP address on my network of the machine which the web socket server is running on):

m_WSClient = new WebSocket("ws://11.22.33.44:3333/Laputa");

I connect like so:

m_WSClient.Connect();

Send a message like so:

m_WSClient?.Send("Test");

and I receive "Elvis Lives!" in my OnMessage listener.

Now, if I want to publish this to azure and have it work how should I change the lines which create the server and the client?

(I have enabled web sockets on my Azure app from the Azure homepage).

Azure requires secure socket connections, so I changed the creation line to:

m_WSServer = new WebSocketServer(3333, **true**);

and of course, the client can no longer use 11.22.33.44 or ws, so I changed this line to:

m_WSClient = new WebSocket("wss://myazureappname.azurewebsites.net/Laputa");

But this does not work, client does not connect.

Is that client url correct, (i.e. same as url of my web app but with wss instead of http)?

and maybe I need to change the server creation line? At the moment it just specifies the port and 'true', there is an overload that takes a URL).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I also tried adding port to client creation like so: as m_WSClient = new WebSocket("wss://myazureappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa"); but still no go.

Comment: Using this [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) to add a WebSocket server to the Web  app sharing the code that I tried

Comment: start a WebSocket connection to the [Azure](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-web-pubsub/howto-websocket-connect.md#start-a-websocket-connection-to-azure-web-pubsub) Web PubSub service in different [languages](https://i.imgur.com/7ze9DbA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) to add a [WebSocket](https://github.com/bjorg/BlazorWebSocket) server to Web  [app](https://github.com/Lupusa87/BlazorWebSocketHelper).

**General  setting Configuration:**
[image]

**Code**:

```js
@page "/"
@using System.Net.WebSockets
@using System.Text
@using System.Threading
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Echo test</h1>
<h3>State: @webSocket.State</h3>

@if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    <form @onsubmit="SendMessageAsync">
        Message: <input @bind="message" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    <pre>@log</pre>
}

@code {
    // Fields
    CancellationTokenSource disposalTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    string message = "Hello, WebSocket!";
    string log = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://your-websocket-url"), disposalTokenSource.Token);
            _ = ReceiveLoop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log += $"Connection error: {ex.Message}\n";
        }
    }

    private async Task SendMessageAsync()
    {
        log += $"Sending: {message}\n";
        var dataToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await webSocket.SendAsync(dataToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, disposalTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLoop()
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        try
        {
            while (!disposalTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var received = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, disposalTokenSource.Token);
                var receivedAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, received.Count);
                log += $"Received: {receivedAsText}\n";
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log += $"Receive error: {ex.Message}\n";
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposalTokenSource.Cancel();
        _ = webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bye", CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**using websocket-sharp with [wss](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp):**

```cs
    {
        // WebSocket Server
        var wssv = new WebSocketServer(5963, true);

        // Provide the SSL certificate and password.
        wssv.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
            "/path/to/cert.pfx", "password for cert.pfx"
        );

        wssv.AddWebSocketService<MyWebSocketBehavior>("/myendpoint");

        try
        {
            wssv.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket Server is running on port 5963 with SSL/TLS.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while starting the WebSocket Server: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        // WebSocket Client
        var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:5963/myendpoint");

        // Customize server certificate validation logic.
        ws.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
            // Implement your custom certificate validation logic here.
            // For simplicity, this example always returns true.
            return true; // If the server certificate is valid.
        };

        try
        {
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received from Server: " + e.Data);
            };

            ws.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket Client connected to the server.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while connecting to the WebSocket Server: " + ex.Message);
            wssv.Stop();
            return;
        }

        // Send data to the server.
        try
        {
            ws.Send("Hello, WebSocket Server!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent to the server.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while sending a message: " + ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

        // Close WebSocket and WebSocket Server
        try
        {
            ws.Close();
            wssv.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while closing the WebSocket or WebSocket Server: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

class MyWebSocketBehavior : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg = e.Data;
        Console.WriteLine("Received from Client: " + msg);

        // Echo the received message back to the client.
        try
        {
            Send("Server received: " + msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while sending a response message: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does it work on azure as well?
using websocket-sharp with localhost or IIS works fine, but we are facing difficulties setting the web socket server on azure. 
We enabled websocket in our web site configuration in azure portal.
calling wssv.start() raises a `underlying listener has failed to start` exception.